# Serialize Class object to flat XML

Tags: c#, xml

I would like to serialise internal class objects to flats. Lets say we have this code:

```
public class ClassA
  {
     public string Identifier {get; set;}
     public ClassB ClassBItem {get; set}
  }

public class ClassB
  {
     public string Name {get; set}
     public string Description {get; set;}
  }
```

I want this to look like this when serialised:

```
<ClassA>
  <Identifier>Some identifier</Identifier>
  <Name>Some name</Name>
  <Description>Some description</Description>
</ClassA>
```

I will make sure there are no duplicate element names. Is it possible to flatten objects like this?

Comment: Cleanest would be to create an intermediary class with the XML structure you desire, translate your objects into it, and then serialize from *that*

Comment: Was hoping I could avoid needing to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Newtonsoft provides a standard library for JSON purposes: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json, it uses a standard serialiser, combined with directives `[XmlElement]`, `[XmlIgnore]`, ... for steering the serialisation.

**Edit**

I'm sorry, I meant the "System.Xml" reference, which gives access to `using System.Xml.Serialization;`. This, in its turn, gives access to directives like `[XmlRoot("newRoot")]`, `[XmlElement("Element_Tag")]` and others in order to serialise to Xml strings like:

```
<newRoot>
  <Element_Tag>a</Element_Tag>
</newRoot>
```

Comment: How would a JSON library help with XML serialization?

Comment: @KlausGütter: You're right, I've corrected my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Dominique. So, with the edit you have made, how can I use that to flatten the internal properties? Are you able to use my example in the explanation? Sorry am struggling to achieve the desired end without transforming into an intermediator class with the correct XML structure.